# Default arguments in Python not consistent

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting unexpected behavior in Python 2.7 when using default arguments. Instead of using the value passed in by the caller, one argument is getting overridden by the default. Consider the following functions:

```
def vm_list(domain, username, server, verbose, cluster, datacenter, name,
            regex, template_only, detailed_list, vm_status):

    print 'inside vm_list vm_stauts is', vm_status
    vcenter_request = "get_registered_vms"
    vmlist = vcenter_connect(server, user, password, vcenter_request, vm_status)

def vcenter_connect(server, user, password, request,
                    source_vm=None, target_vm=None,
                    res_pool=None, num=1, vm_status=None):

    print 'inside vcenter_connect vm_stauts is', vm_status
```

`vm_list` gets called first with `vm_status` passed in as a string, such as "poweredOff". Inside this function `vm_status` is equal to `"poweredOff"` as expected, but when I pass the value to `vcenter_connect` it's getting overridden by the default argument `None`. I am using other default arguments in `vcenter_connect` but they are working as expected, that is, they're only using the default values when nothing is passed in.

Running the relevent parts to test the string value gives me this:

```
inside vm_list vm_stauts is poweredOff
inside vcenter_connect vm_stauts is None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `vm_status` as the 5th positional parameter to `vcenter_connect`, but the 5th positional parameter to that function is `source_vm`, so `vm_status` gets its default of `None`.

Instead, you must tell it which keyword parameter you are sending after the first 4 positional ones:

```
vmlist = vcenter_connect(server, user, password, vcenter_request, vm_status=vm_status)
```

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick. This is a learning step for me as I'm not quite used to keyword parameters.